# how to get value generated in mock method

Tags: mockito

I have a service method in `FooService`

```
public void doSomething(){
    ArrayList<Foo> fooList = ...;
    barService.batchAddFoos(fooList); 

    List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Foo foo : fooList) {
        codeList.add(foo.getCode());
    }
    String key = "foo_codes";
    redisService.sadd(key,codeList.toArray(new String[]{}));
    // other code also need use code
}
```

`BarService.batchAddFoos`

```
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        foo.setCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // dynamically generate the code value
    }
```

Then I have a unit test to test FooService logic

```
@Test
public void doSomething() throws Exception {
    fooService.doSomething();
    ArgumentCaptor<List<Foo>> fooListCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
    verify(barService).batchAddFoos(fooListCaptor.capture());
    List<Foo> fooList = fooListCaptor.getValue();
    Assert.assertNotNull(fooList.get(0).getCode()); // check code value is generated successfully
    List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Foo foo : fooList) {
        codeList.add(foo.getCode());
    }
    verify(redisService).sadd("foo_codes",codeList.toArray(new String[]{}));
}
```

but it is failed, because the `code` value is null, actually it does not execute any code in `BarService.batchAddFoos`.I even tried to explicitly populate code value,

```
    fooList.get(0).setCode("aaa");
    fooList.get(1).setCode("bbb");
```

but it is still failed.

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
redisService.sadd("foo_codes", "aaa", "bbb");
Actual invocation has different arguments:
redisService.sadd("foo_codes", null, null);
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to not test `FooService` as a single unit under test, but to use a `FooService` with the real `BarService` injected as a larger unit under test, because there is this hidden dependency by modifying object state in `BarService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such scenario, could populate some properties of some object parameters as you like, e.g.

```
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            List<Foo> fooList = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0, List.class);
            fooList.get(0).setCode("aaa"); // explicitly specify the first foo object have code of "aaa"
            fooList.get(1).setCode("bbb"); // explicitly specify the second foo object have code of "bbb"
            return null;
        }
    }).when(barService).batchAddFoos(anyList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the *fooList* is a local variable of the *FooService.doSomething*, you cannot populate it from the test. Your test will not fail, if assertion will be as following:

```
Mockito.verify(barService).batchAddFoos(fooListCaptor.capture());
List<Foo> fooList = fooListCaptor.getValue();
//Assert.assertNotNull(fooList.get(0).getCode());
Assert.assertFalse(fooList.isEmpty());
...
```

If you will initialize the *code* in the *Foo* constructor with **Strings.EMPTY** or any other **not null** value, your original assertion will work.

Comment: Please see my below answer, actually you can populate it from the test

Comment: In your own answer you mock the barService.batchAndFoos. But the original question is about argument capture. By the way, to mock it you should not override - just fill the foo list and put when(barService.batchAndFoos(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(fooList) before call to doSomething().

Comment: but it is a void method.

Comment: Get it. Still it is not clear, what are your trying to test. Is it FooService or BarService? I suggest you to edit the question and clarify, what problem you are trying to solve.